# C++: проверка строки

Tags: c++, строки

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int hp=100;
char start[20];

void draw() {
    system("color 7");
}

void enter_start(){
    cout <<"Добро пожаловать в CPP Wars!" <<endl;
    cout <<"Введите 'Start' для начала игры" <<endl;
    cin >>start;
    cout <<"Начинаем игру!" <<endl;
    system("cls");
}

void game(){
    cout <<"У вас " <<hp <<" делаем ход" <<endl;
    if (rand()% 2 == 0) {
        system("color a");
        cout <<"Вас ударили -1 hp!" <<endl;
        hp-=1;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
    }
    else {
        system("color c");
        cout <<"Вы восстановили силы +1 hp" <<endl;
        hp+=1;
        Sleep(2000);
        system("cls");
    }


}

void check(){
    if (start=="Start") {
        game();
    }
    else {
        cout <<"Команда введена не верно! Повторите попытку " <<start <<endl;

    }
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    while(hp > 0){
        draw();
        enter_start();
        check();
    }
    system ("color 4");
    cout <<"Игра окончена" <<endl;
    cout <<"Вы умерли..." <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Функция `check()` почему-то не работает, при вводе `"Start"` она все равно выводит сообщение о том, что `"Команда введена не верно!"` Не могу понять, где я ошибся, прошу вашей помощи!

Comment: А какую строку вы вводите? Регистр здесь важен

Comment: @free_ze, я понимаю, что регистр важен. Поэтому ввожу то, что проверяю, у меня char'ная переменная. Может в этом проблема?

Comment: Ух. Как же мы можем вам помочь, если не предоставили весь нужный код? Мы же не телепаты. [Прочитайте вот это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Покажите код программы целиком (но сначала выбросьте из него все, что не относится к проблеме), чтобы мы могли скомпилировать его у себя и проверить.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat обновил, вставил весь код!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Классический косяк со сравнением строк через указатели.

У вас `==` сравнивает не содержимое строк, а их адреса. Раз это две отдельные строки, то адреса всегда разные, и возвращается всегда `false`.

---

В C++ не принято использовать массивы символов для хранения строк (без большой необходимости). Для этого есть `std::string`.

Замените `char start[20];` на `std::string start;`, и все заработает. Не забудьте добавить `#include <string>`.

<sup>(Раз у вас стоит `using namespace std;`, то `string start;` тоже подойдет. Но `using namespace std;` - вещь [не очень хорошая](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), я бы советовал от нее отказаться.)</sup>

Кроме того, это решает проблему со вводом большего количества символов, чем есть места в массиве. `std::string` сама растянулась бы до нужного размера, а выход за границы `char name[20];` вызовет неопределенное поведение, и, скорее всего, вылет.

---

Если вы настаиваете на `char name[20]`, то для сравнения его с другой строкой используйте [`std::strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). Так это делается в <s>варварских землях</s> С, где нет такой роскоши, как `std::string`.

Либо используйте цикл и сравнивайте строки посимвольно, но в этом мало смысла, ведь `strcmp` уже делает то же самое.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ мне помог! Все понятно и ясно, удачи вам!

Answer (score 2):

Понимаете, сравнение переменных типа

```
char str[];
```

или

```
char * str;
```

со строковым литералом (или между собой - неважно)

```
str == "String"
```

сравнивает два **указателя** - `str` и указатель на строковый литерал, но не содержимое строк. Очевидно, что это два разных указателя, и такое сравнение всегда ложно.

Строки в стиле C сравниваются с помощью функции [`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). С помощью оператора `==` можно сравнивать содержимое строк типа `string` (но это не ваш случай, если только вы не выполните преобразование в `string`...).